# How do I set the jax-ws client request timeout programatically on jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to set the request (and connection) timeout for a jax-ws-webservice-client generated with the jaxws-maven-plugin. When running my app under tomcat or jetty the timeout works, but when deployed under jboss it doesn't "take".

```
private void setRequestAndConnectionTimeout(Object wsPort) {
  String REQUEST_TIMEOUT = BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT; // "com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout";
  ((BindingProvider) wsPort).getRequestContext().put(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, timeoutInMillisecs);
  ((BindingProvider) wsPort).getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, timeoutInMillisecs);
}
```

What is the correct way to do this for JBoss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with this code in Jboss:

```
(BindingProvider)wsPort).getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, yourTimeoutInMillisec);
```

Have a look to [this](http://community.jboss.org/thread/101684?tstart=0) thread.

Comment: That solves it!

StubExt is in:
    import org.jboss.ws.core.StubExt;


Had to add some maven dependencies:
     <dependency>
      <groupId>jboss-eap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbossws-spi</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.GA_CP02</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>jboss-eap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbossws-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.0.GA_CP02</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

Thanks a lot!